# R targets pipeline error: "Error : _paths_ missing files:" D:/path_to_my_file

Tags: r, export-to-csv, targets-r-package

I am learning to use `targets` within my current research project. I am still at the beginning of my data processing (and associated pipeline) but I get the following error when I try to use `targets::tar_make()`:

```
> targets::tar_make()
✔ skip target raw_tits
• start target nnestling_data
ℹ Using "','" as decimal and "'.'" as grouping mark. Use `read_delim()` for more control.
✖ error target nnestling_data
• end pipeline: 1.19 seconds
Error : _paths_ missing files: Table exported to D:/fmartin/Mes documents/projects/pubprivlands/analyses/ppl.tits/output/tables/tits_nestling_data.csv
✖ Problem with the pipeline.
ℹ Show errors: tar_meta(fields = error, complete_only = TRUE)
ℹ Learn more: https://books.ropensci.org/targets/debugging.html
Error:
! problem with the pipeline.
```

I truly don't understand why it doesn't work since there is **no missing file**. Here's how my current `_targets.R` looks like:

```
list(
  # Make the workflow depends on the raw data file
  targets::tar_target(raw_data_file, here::here("mydata", "ppl_dijon_tits_data.csv"),
             format = "file"),
  # Read the data and return a data.frame
  targets::tar_target(raw_tits, ppl.tits::import_raw_tits_data()),
  # Export the nestling aggregated data table
  targets::tar_target(nnestling_data, ppl.tits::export_nestling_aggreg(), format = "file")
  )
```

And the simple export function I'm calling in my last `targets::tar_target()`:

```
export_nestling_aggreg <- function(){
  aabb <- ppl.tits::aggreg_by_nest()
  readr::write_csv2(x = aabb, file = here::here("output", "tables", "tits_nestling_data.csv"))
  return(paste("Table exported to", here::here("output", "tables", "tits_nestling_data.csv"), sep = " "))
}
```

Could someone help me figure this one out?

Comment: The file it is looking for is `D:/path/to/my/file.csv`, which I don't see in your code, whereas `export_nestling_aggreg()` returns a different CSV file path. Did you forget to save an R script you were editing?

Comment: @landau I modified the code posted here to hide the personal information of my computer, hence the `D:/path/to/my/file.csv` (the true path indeed ends with `output/tables/tits_nestling_data.csv` as shown in my custom function). There is no mistake here and all files are saved, but I will edit my question to put the true paths in case I made mistakes (thank you, btw).

Comment: Ah, I think it’s the “Table exported to” part of the string. The function writing the file should return exactly the path written, without any extra text. As it stands, {targets} thinks your file is in a folder called “Table exported to D:/fmartin/“.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled because I already tried to remove this part of code but it did not worked at the time and now... it does! I must have missed something. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @landau, I just noticed another problem. When I try `targets::tar_make()`, the code now runs (thanks to you) but it does not actually export the table as requested, it simply writes the path to the folder. I noticed it because I updated my input dataset (i.e. ppl_dijon_tits_data.csv) but when I ran `targets::tar_make()`, it did not update the exported table as it should have (that's the whole point of `targets`, keeping track of changes and updating only the parts affected by the changes, right?). Any idea why?

Comment: Did the content of the input dataset change, or did you make a trivial change to the input file? Because if the data frame you get out of that has the same hash as last time, then {targets} won’t actually consider it a change even if the timestamp changed.

Comment: The number of rows is the same but I corrected some mistakes in the cells.

Comment: Hard to say because I don’t have your data, so I can’t run your pipeline. If you reproduce the same behavior with a dataset I can access, I may have better advice.

Comment: You can clone my project if you want (https://github.com/mrelnoob/ppl.tits). This is an R package that I am developing to help me organise the data analysis process linked to my research project. However, as I am a mediocre R user and since I hadn't the time to properly read the {targets} documentation (sorry), you'll probably find a lot of clumsy programming. The good point is that I write my R files with much comments to help future me (and others) reproduce my work so it's quite straightforward.

Comment: I ran https://github.com/mrelnoob/ppl.tits/commit/32f1b9f78afd9f28dfc2a7930692f560cc325f70 with no issue (after installing your package). Looks like you fixed the error since we last spoke.

Comment: I did nothing of the sort, at least not on purpose, but I'm glad as long as it works. I should truly read the {targets} documentation. Thanks anyway!